# MKMapView not loading on mapType MKMapTypeStandard and MKMapTypeHybrid

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I am developing an app in which 3 different maptype have to load.

1. MKMapTypeStandard
2. MKMapTypeHybrid.
3. MKMapTypeSatellite.

MKMapTypeSatellite working fine but when load map in MKMapTypeStandard and MKMapTypeHybrid. It call following delegate method

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error;
```

It give me following error.

UserInfo={SimpleTileRequesterUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 \"(null)\" UserInfo={HTTPStatus=410, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://gspe19.ls.apple.com/tile.vf?flags=1&style=1&size=2&scale=0&v=11043961&z=12&x=660&y=1590&sid=1311957767904651942802757092322405105280&accessKey=1462435981_hSWhfZAWqY7wbLSz_6yKz632EUigAIfHlARfHz5OZnObk4SFpRyFZH9qim7suxznqeD333wldHPDaCADTpx1hD98l55WMoqg6qjh2BMyZtDwLayiLzpSWLxfuYD4Oi%2BI3wB%2BGvMwttokk5y8UlnR1E68zLU6KuXF4MWLKLhvv%2F6utSC8RDmorsQksacSTvCwYc45PeV5ba%2Fjvt2d3}"....

I am switching map type

```
-(IBAction)valuechange:(id)sender{
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard ;
            break;

        case 1:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite ;
            break;

        case 2:
            _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid ;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

[image][image][image]

**UPDATE:**
I think i have similar issue 
[MKMapView fails to load tiles with HTTP 410 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35226550/1320352)

when i reboot the simulator. Now map load perfectly. same my client tell me that if he kill the app on his device map loading perfectly. but every fresh load app having this issue. i am getting frustrated now. :(

Comment: wow, 5 upvotes in 13 minutes :)

Comment: @DudeDeveloper You are testing it in device or simulator?

Comment: actually my client having this issue in his device. i have issue in in my simulator

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me.. check below if you having some modifications.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:
           CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.32, -122.03);
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double) 37.332768;
location.longitude = (double) -122.030039;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"MKMapTypeHybrid" andCoordinate:location];
[mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location2;
location2.latitude = (double) 37.35239;
location2.longitude = (double) -122.025919;
MapAnnotation *newAnnotation2 = [[MapAnnotation alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"MKMapTypeHybrid" andCoordinate:location2];
[mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation2];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];

}


// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it (1500 range)
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{

MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];

}
```

Just change the values 
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

MKMapTypeStandard, MKMapTypeHybrid & MKMapTypeSatellite

I have posted the images, too if you want to check.

[image: MKMapTypeHybrid]

[image: MKMapTypeSatellite]

[image: MKMapTypeStandard]

Comment: I have similar code. it is working on my device but on simulator its not working. My client having issue on his device. Weird... no luck :(

Comment: I have tested it in simulator & its working fine. You might be missing something, check once again.